# Header menus from right to left

Tags: html, css, menu

I have made a website header in photoshop and i am having a problem making the navigation work.I want my menu to start
from the right say point(940 px).My menus should grow from right to left and mustn't go past a certain point,in my 
image that point is point (251 px).I have some basic css but i need help to proceed from here.

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Header</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<!-- Save for Web Styles (header1.png) -->
<style type="text/css">
<!--

#header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:940px;
    height:100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -470px;

}

#fancy_strip {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:940px;
    height:11px;
}

#logo {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:11px;
    width:251px;
    height:89px;
}
#navigation {
    position:absolute;
    left:250px;
    top:37px;
    width:689px;
    height:33px;
}
-->
</style>
<!-- End Save for Web Styles -->
</head>
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (header1.png) -->
<div id="header">
    <div id="fancy_strip">
        <img src="images/header1_01.gif" width="940" height="11" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/header1_02.gif" width="192" height="89" alt="">
    </div>

    <div id="navigation">
    Home / Products / Services
     </div>

</div>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if you put your menu in a `<div style="float: right; width:689px ">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#navigation { text-align: right; } for starters
```